# Get all nodes of left side in binary tree using sql server

Tags: sql-server, tree, binary-tree, hierarchical-data

Suppose I have a tree

```
                     RootNode
             -----------|------------
            |                        |
            AL                       AR
        ----|-----             ------|-------
       |          |           |              |
      ZL         ZR           BL             BR
                           ---|---       ----|---- 
                          |       |     |         |
                          CL      CR    DL        DR
```

AL,ZL, ZR are left side nodes of root node.
AR, BL, BR, CL, CR, DL , DR are the right side nodes.

In the same way for right side.
This should repeat for each and every node in the tree and should display the sum of total members of left & right.

Thanks in advance for the help and please help me in this scenario.

SQL TABLE STRUCTURE :

```
[MastId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MastCode] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
[MastName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[JoiningDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[LU_MemberRankId] [int] NOT NULL,
[TreeId_Parent] [int] NOT NULL,
[TreeId_Child_Left] [int] NOT NULL,
[TreeId_Child_Right] [int] NOT NULL,
[TreeLevelNo] [int] NOT NULL,
[SponParentId] [int] NOT NULL,
[SponChildCount] [int] NOT NULL,
[SponChildCount_Left] [int] NOT NULL,
[SponChildCount_Right] [int] NOT NULL,
[TotChildCount_Left] [int] NOT NULL,
[TotChildCount_Right] [int] NOT NULL,
[RemChildCount_Left] [int] NOT NULL,
[RemChildCount_Right] [int] NOT NULL,
[PreferenceSideId] [int] NOT NULL,
[AllChildCount_Left] [int] NOT NULL,
[AllChildCount_Right] [int] NOT NULL,
[AllRemChildCount_Left] [int] NOT NULL,
[AllRemChildCount_Right] [int] NOT NULL,
[LU_MemberStatusId] [int] NOT NULL,
[LU_GenderId] [int] NOT NULL,
[DOB] [date] NOT NULL,
[TotPurchase] [decimal](15, 2) NOT NULL,
[ActivationDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[RemPurchase] [decimal](15, 2) NOT NULL
```

[Find the SQL Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZPip.jpg)

Comment: What data structure do you use to store the tree?

Comment: Hi Paul Spiegel, I had updated post with table Structure and also attached Data values.

Comment: SQL Server already has a `hierarchyid` type that can be used to represent hierarchies. All you need is to add a `hierarchyid` column. As for the table structure, it doesn't make any sense as it is. Try to format it at least and *explain* what the various fields are supposed to do. It looks like a mix of both nested sets and adjacency list without the functions required to make this work. All the `count` fields suggest you run into performance problems and though to cache the values

Comment: Check the tutorial [Using the hierarchyid data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677213.aspx) to see how you can easily work with trees

Comment: NEED ANSWER.. NOT ABLE TO UNDERSTAND..